# OpenVPN works, but other connections to the server are bypassing the VPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

My client machine (Windows 7) connects to the server's (Ubuntu) OpenVPN fine, but when I want to access the server's website, those connections are not routing through the VPN...  How do I amend this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may consider add the **push "redirect-gateway"** option to your OpenVPN configuration.

```
# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# the TUN/TAP interface to the internet in
# order for this to work properly).
# CAVEAT: May break client's network config if
# client's local DHCP server packets get routed
# through the tunnel.  Solution: make sure
# client's local DHCP server is reachable via
# a more specific route than the default route
# of 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0.
push "redirect-gateway"
```

Regards.

Comment: I already have that pushed.  Still, cannot access content on the server itself via the tunnel.